# Find the radius of convergence of the Taylor series of $\frac {1}{2+x^2}$ about x=2

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

My attempt:
$$\frac {1}{2+x^2}=\frac {1}{6+[(x-2)^2+4(x-2)]}=\frac{1}{6[1-\frac {(-(x-2)^2)-4(x-2)]}{6}]}$$
This final expression can be treated in the form $\frac {1}{6(1-y)}$ where $y=\frac {-(x-2)^2-4(x-2)}{6}$.
We know that $$\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n for |y|<1$$
Thus the required Taylor series should be $$\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac {-(x-2)^2-4(x-2)}{6})^n$$
Using binomial expansion this series can be expressed as $$\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}(x-2)+\frac{5}{108}(x-2)^2+...$$
We know that this series should converge for $|y|<1$ or $$|\frac {-(x-2)^2-4(x-2)}{6}|<1$$
This gives the interval of convergence to be $(-\sqrt10,\sqrt10)$. However if this series was a power series, there should exist a no non-negative real number R such that the series converges for $|x-2|<R$. However I am not able to find any such radius of convergence R for this series. So can I conclude that the series that I have come up with is not a power series and hence not a Taylor series as every Tailor series is a power series?

Comment: There are singularities at $x=\pm\sqrt{2}i$ so$R=\text{min}(|2-\sqrt{2}i|,|2-(-\sqrt{2}i)|)=\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the series do the partial fraction decomposition and make appear the $x-2$ term: $$\frac{1}{2+x^2}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}i/2}{x-\sqrt{2}i}+\frac{\sqrt{2}i/2}{x+\sqrt{2}i}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}i/2}{(x-2)+2-\sqrt{2}i}+\frac{\sqrt{2}i/2}{(x-2)+2+\sqrt{2}i}$$

Then this is equal to (by taking out the factors) $$\frac{-\sqrt{2}i/2}{2-\sqrt{2}i}\frac{1}{1+(x-2)/(2-\sqrt{2}i)}+
\frac{\sqrt{2}i/2}{2+\sqrt{2}i}\frac{\sqrt{2}i/2}{1+(x-2)/(2+\sqrt{2}i)}$$

Now, use with each fraction that $\frac{1}{1+y}=1-y+y^2-y^3+y^4-y^5+...$ For the first fraction put $y=(x-2)/(2-\sqrt{2}i)$ and for the second put $y=(x-2)/(2+\sqrt{2}i)$.

---

However, you don't need to compute the series to tell the radius of convergence. The series is known to converge from the center to the nearest singularity. This function has singularities at $x=\pm\sqrt{2}i$. The distance from them to $2$ is $|2\pm\sqrt{2}i|=\sqrt{2^2+2}=\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: So the series that I found is not a power series?

Comment: @AKASHASHOK The series that you found is not written as a power series centered at $2$. $\sum_na_n(x-2)^n$. It could lead to one, but will will be hard to write down the coefficients. The term with the power $n$ contributes to the coefficients of degrees $n,n+1,...,2n$ in the final expansion.

Comment: @AKASHASHOK Observe also that you tested for the absolute convergence of your series, which can be thought as a re-ordering and grouping of the actual power series. Remember that re-ordering and grouping the terms of a series can change the convergence and sum of the series. For example $1-1+1-1+1-1+...$ is divergent, while $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+...$ converges.

Comment: According to this source, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence if a series is absolutely convergent in a given interval, then every rearrangement of that series must also be absolutely convergent in that interval. Since my series converges absolutely in the interval $(-\sqrt10,\sqrt10)$, wont it imply that the actual power series also converges in the same interval?

Comment: @AKASHASHOK Yes, but observe that you are testing the absolute convergence *after* the re-ordering and the grouping. For example, $1-1+1-1+...$ and $(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+...$ still give divergent $1+|-1|+1+|-1|+...$ and convergent $|1-1|+|1-1|+|1-1|+...$.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get you. The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {-(x-2)^2-4(x-2)}{6})^n$ converges absolutely for x belonging to $(-\sqrt10,\sqrt10)$ and the series after reordering and grouping becomes the power series $\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{9}(x-2)+\frac{5}{108}(x-2)^2+...$. My claim is that since the series before reordering converges absolutely on $(-\sqrt10,\sqrt10)$, the power series obtained after reordering should also converge on $(-\sqrt10,\sqrt10)$.

Comment: @AKASHASHOK Yes, that implication is wrong. The theorem that you know tells you that if $|a_1|+|a_2|+...$ converges, then $a_{n_1}+a_{n_2}+...$ converges. However, what you are doing is breaking up each $a_n=b_{n,1}+b_{n,2}+...+b_{n,n}$ into $n$ terms and re-arranging and grouping the new series $\sum b_{i,j}$. The absolute convergence of $a_1+a_2+...$ tells you nothing about the convergence of $\sum b_{i,j}$

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks a lot!